# How to use own types instead of scala standard types in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt, read-eval-print-loop

I have the following for learning.

```
package learning.laziness

sealed trait Stream[+A] {
  def headOption: Option[A] = this match {
    case Empty => None
    case Cons(h, _) => Some(h())
  }

  def toList: List[A] = this match {
    case Empty => List.empty
    case Cons(h,t) => h()::t().toList
  }
}
case object Empty extends Stream[Nothing]
case class Cons[A](head: () => A, tail: () => Stream[A]) extends Stream[A]

object Stream {
  def cons[A](hd: => A, tl: => Stream[A]): Stream[A] = {
    lazy val head = hd
    lazy val tail = tl
    Cons(() => head, () => tail)
  }
  def empty[A]: Stream[A] = Empty
  def apply[A](as: A*): Stream[A] =
    if (as.isEmpty) empty else cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))
}
```

When I load the REPL via `sbt console` and enter for example

- `Stream(1,2)`

  - `res0: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)`
- `Stream.apply(1,2)`

  - `res1: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)`
- `Stream.cons(1, Stream.cons(2, Stream.empty))`

  - `res2: Stream.Cons[Int] = Stream(1, ?)`

It uses Stream from scala.collection.immutable in the two first cases instead of mine. How can I make sbt only use mine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the *SBT console*, import your class before attempting to use it:

```
scala> import learning.laziness.Stream
scala> Stream(1, 2)
scala> //etc.
```

Your `Stream` class's code must be under an *SBT* source folder (by default, this would be `src/main/scala`, relative to the project root directory, or in a custom source directory specified by an *SBT* `scalaSource in Compile` directive - it will not be found and compiled by *SBT* otherwise). As the code you provide is in the package `learning.laziness`, then the default location for your `Stream.scala` source file would need to be `src/main/scala/learning/laziness`. Once *SBT* knows where to find your file, you should then be fine.

Comment: This gives me an error:
`scala> import learning.laziness.Stream
<console>:11: error: not found: value learning
       import learning.laziness.Stream`

Comment: @mrt181 Is your _SBT_ build a multi-project build by any chance?

Comment: no, my build.sbt only has this `scalaVersion := "2.12.2"`

Comment: @mrt181 Where is the location of your Stream class? If you've followed the standard convention, it ought to be in src/main/scala/learning/laziness/Stream.scala, relative to your project's root directory. If so, the code I specified should work; if not, then in which directory is your Stream source code?

Comment: it was in `src/learning/laziness/Stream.scala`. after fixing that it works through importing my code. Can you update your answer so I can accept that.

Comment: @mrt181 What do I need to update? Did you you move your source file to the standard location?

Comment: yes, I did that. Can you add that to your answer: "move your code to the standard location `src/main/scala` then in the SBT....